# Issues using google drive api to read the list of files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api

I was following the new google drive api for the requirement to search a particular doc with title at https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

However, the code seems to show the requirement of user interaction in the lines:

```
 String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine()
```

We were earlier using Documents API to do the same in our google app engine for java app. But looks like google broke it as our code stopped working all of a sudden.

So, how to search and read a google text document using the google drive api?

Comment: I looked into server side APIs but looks like from google app engine the reading of docs should be simpler https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side implementation seems to be the way to go https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server